# Reading lines out of a file and putting them into a string array

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

What I would like to do is be able to read a line out of a file and stick it into an array of strings.  This is what I have so far but it does not seem to work.

```
...
char line [128];
char file [10][128];

plist = fopen("plist1.txt", "r");

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, plist) != NULL){
   file[i][0]= line;
   i++;
}
```

I tried doing `file[i][0] = *line;` and I was able to print out the first character of each line.  Is this the best way to do what I am trying to do?

Also, the number of lines in a text file will vary so I would like to have my array be of variable length instead of 10.

EDIT:  I have tried two solution listed below.  Both give me a segmentation fault dealing with either strcpy or the fgets.

```
1.  while (fgets(file[i], sizeof(file[i]), plist))
       i++;

2.  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), plist)){
       strcpy(file[i], line);
       i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
while (fgets(file[i], sizeof(file[i]), plist))
    i++;
```

Alternatively

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), plist))
    strcpy(file[i], line);
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  I ALWAYS forget they are pointers and not actual values :/.  Stupid errors always get me.

Comment: @user972276 My heart is bleeding. Use a debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fully working solution, assuming `plist1.txt` contains a line of text per line. `fgets()` will by default also include a newline at the end, that you need to get rid of. It is also a good idea to use symbolic constants so that you can change them easily later on if you so want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF 128 /* can change the buffer size as well */
#define TOT 10 /* change to accomodate other sizes, change ONCE here */

int main(void) {
    char line[TOT][BUF];
    FILE *plist = NULL; 
    int i = 0;
    int total = 0;

    plist = fopen("plist1.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(line[i], BUF, plist)) {
        /* get rid of ending \n from fgets */
        line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }

    total = i;

    for(i = 0; i < total; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", line[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am having a problem with the fgets.  It is giving me a segmentation fault.

Comment: Can you post your plist1.txt you're working with? Here's mine:
Hello\n
Hello world\n
Hi\n
Testing

Comment: @user972276 probably your TOT is too large

Comment: Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at 
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/code/216411

Comment: I used that.  My problem was that every element in my array pointed to the variable line.  So all elements in my array pointed to the same string.  I did not realize this was my problem till the first comment.   Thanks for helping!  just a stupid error...